# angular 2 load js library on demand when route call

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, lazy-loading

working on angular2 web application, application libraries and dependencies increasing as time spent.. so now when my `index.html` page load it takes more time than usual.

there are near about 15-20 javascript libraries which I am calling in page.

so I want to config app in the way that when specific module/route called then only it's required dependencies and libraries will called.

just for an example, I have `company contact us page` inside that I am loading `google map` so I want to load it's js file only when when it's route `/contact` will be called.

here's my **google map api** call in **index.html**

```
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my-key" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my-key" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

now I am using this in my component company-contact. inside that as well I have **child component for google map load** so now I want to lazy load the resources when this module/component called(child or parent).

so **I want to call my google map js file inside my contact component**, so like this I can make **index.html** more lighter than before.

I have seen that we can load **css** specific to component so is there anyway we can call js as well ?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'contact',
    templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../assets/dmaterial/theme/css/dmaterial-theme.css'],
})
```

any suggestions please..

Answer (score 1):

there no way to do so (**by angular itself**) but you can use other ways suggested here -> https://jmperezperez.com/ondemand-javascript-lazy-loading-stubs/

Comment: in my case, how does it work ! I am new to angular2 so can you guide me ?